# Configuration to get new user email confirmation

Tags: magento-1.9, email, user

I set the Require Emails Confirmation in System->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configurations to Yes but im not getting any email.
I wonder if i need any more configuration to make the confirmation emails to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your server setup to send out emails?  This is not on all servers by default.

Comment: Did you set the store contact e-mail addresses correctly?